# cosets partitioning group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$ such that $|G| = k * |H|$.

Is it true that for any $g \in G$ \ $H$ (here the notation means $g$ in the set $G$ but not in $H$) that $H, gH, g^2H, \dots , g^{k-1}H$ are disjoint i.e partition $G$?

Comment: Assuming finite groups, right?

Comment: Use that $aH=bH$ iff $a^{-1}b\in H$

Comment: @janmarqz you only get that for  some $i < k$,  $g^i \in K$ so not a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true only if $G/H$ is a cyclic group of order $k$, generated by the congruence class of $g$.